# Laravel 5 adding an element in an array does not work

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, eloquent

I am getting an array from table questions

```
$questions = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first()->questions->toArray();
```

then using foreach I iterate over array and push an array element during each iteration like below

```
foreach ($questions as $question) {
        $question['options'] = Option::where('question_id', $question['id'])->get()->toArray();
    }
```

Ideally I should get response like below

```
array (size=5)
0 => 
array (size=6)
  'id' => int 1
  'category_id' => int 1
  'questions' => string 'The ozone layer restricts' (length=25)
  'answer_id' => int 4
  'image_path' => string '' (length=0)
  'options' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
      3 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
1 => 
array (size=6)
  'id' => int 2
  'category_id' => int 1
  'questions' => string 'Ecology deals with' (length=18)
  'answer_id' => int 10
  'image_path' => string '' (length=0)
  'options' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
      3 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
```

but Actually I am not getting options key into my questions array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is when you do a foreach, you are referring to the array by value - that is, under the hood PHP will create a *copy* of the variable inside the array. What you need is to access each element in the foreach by reference (note the `&` next to `$q`)

```
foreach ($questions as & $q) {
        $q['options'] = Option::where('question_id', '=', $q['id'])->get()->toArray();
}
```

See:
[Passing by references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and [the PHP docs on foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Note: This is not really a Laravel issue, just PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (& in foreach):

```
foreach ($questions as & $question) {
        $question['options'] = Option::where('question_id', $question['id'])->get()->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
foreach ($questions as $key=>$question) {
    $questions[$key]['options'] = Option::where('question_id',$question['id'])->get()->toArray();
}
```